# 12.04 gnome shell broken after updates

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and using gnome shell.

I've had my machine running for the last few days, and I've been installing updates as the update manager bugs me. I just rebooted, and now gnome won't start. I can use gnome classic and unity, but gnome 3 isn't working at all.

When I log in, the screen is black for maybe 20 seconds, but the cursor shows. Then, my wallpaper, but nothing else shows up.

I can get a terminal with ctrl+alt+t, and I tried to run gnome-shell, but it segfaulted.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reinstalling my graphics drivers (proprietary amd), and that did the trick.